# Javascript If Statement won't run

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

The if statement will not run. I'm wondering if anyone can spot the problem as I can't.

```
var a=parseFloat(document.form2.mark1.value);
var b=parseFloat(document.form2.mark2.value);
var c=parseFloat(document.form2.mark3.value);

var total2=(a+b);
if (total2 < 70) 
{ 
    document.form2.realmark.value= "You Have received a Passed";
}
else if(total2 < 89)
{
    document.form2.realmark.value= "You Have received a Ultra passed";
}
else if(total2 < 100)
{
    document.form2.realmark.value= "You Have received Passed Insane";
}
else
{
    window.alert("broken");
}
```

And I am calling it via a button which works if I don't have the if statement.

```
<input name="button4" id="button4" type="button" value="Calculate Overal Mark" onClick="getmark2()" />
<br /><br />
<b>Overall Mark:</b>
<input name="realmark" type="text" id="realmark" size="35" readonly="readonly" />
```

it wont even run the `window.alert("broken");` at the bottom.

Comment: What does 'it won't run' mean? Is this all your code?

Comment: it is running, total2 doesnt hit any of the if statements so it alerts "broken"

Comment: Why do you think any of the if statements would work?

Comment: `var total2 = 100`, all your "ifs" check if it's `< 100`, they are working fine.

Comment: Did you mean `<=` instead?

Comment: it wont work at all it will not run window.alert("broken"); from it

Comment: There's no reason what you're showing shouldn't work.  Check your error console and see what it says.

Comment: @user3163633 is the js above ***actually in a function called getmark2()*** ??

Comment: I think I know your issue but I couldn't find place to answer it :(

Answer (score 5):

**It's doing precisely what you told it to do.**

`total2` is set to 100, but all your `if` statements are programmed to execute only when `total2` is *less than* 100.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear that you know how to write such a code:

```
var total2 = 100;
if (total2 < 70) 
{ 
    document.form2.realmark.value= "You Have recieved a Passed";
}
else if(total2 < 89 && total2 >= 70)
{
    document.form2.realmark.value= "You Have recieved a Ultra passed";
}
else if(total2 < 100 && total2 >= 90)
{
    document.form2.realmark.value= "You Have recieved Passed Insane";
}
else
{
    window.alert("broken");
}
```

And regarding your question, you're setting your `total2 = 100` so your `total2` is one hundred and it is not being caught in any of your `if statements`. So your code in `else` runs since none of the `if conditions` matched.

Comment: As long as `total<70` is run before `total<89`, it doesn't make any difference to add `&&>70`

Comment: I know, That's why I started my comment as "Just to be clear"

Answer (score 0):

Also, a nicer way to do such a huge list of `if`s is to use a switch instead:

```
var a = parseFloat(document.form2.mark1.value);
var b = parseFloat(document.form2.mark2.value);
var c = parseFloat(document.form2.mark3.value);
var total2 = (a+b);

switch(true){
    case (total2 < 70):
        document.form2.realmark.value= "You Have recieved a Passed";
        break;
    case (total2 < 89):
        document.form2.realmark.value= "You Have recieved a Ultra passed";
        break;
    case (total2 < 100):
        document.form2.realmark.value= "You Have recieved Passed Insane";
        break;
    default:
        window.alert("broken");
        break;
}
```

Note that this is mostly programmer preference. Also note that not all languages allow expressions in `case` conditions.